# Visual Studio Cannot Run Project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mcafee

In VS Professional 2019 when I attempt to start my WPF Windows project with debugging I get an error message that says "Error while trying to run project. Access is Denied". Then McAfee LiveSafe AV pops up a message warning me that it's found "Real Protect-LS!B1465A32DC7D" virus and blocks the .EXE file in the debug folder.

When I use McAfee to "restore" the .EXE file, then scan the whole project folder; the AV says no viruses found. Other projects I'm working on are fine.

I found one SO article that suggests to turn on native debugging, but that made no difference. I searched Google for the virus name and most links talk about it as being a false positive.

Does anyone know how to fix this? My dev work has ground to a halt!

Comment: In your AV software (both McAffee and Windows Security) add the entire folder to exclusion list so that it doesn't scan the files for viruses when they are modified. This will also improve performance.

Comment: @DeanKuga I tried this already, but McAfee only allows you to exclude specific files and the file gets automatically removed every time it changes. so after each rebuild I have to add it again. so frustrating. I don't know why this has just started happening, and its specific to one project.

Comment: @DeanKuga also, in Windows Security - Virus & threat protection there is no "Manage Settings" link, so I can't see any way to add/remove exclusions.

Comment: Do you have the permission for the exe? Did it work if you turn off the antivirus software? If it didn't work, could you try to run it in the other devices to check it ok or not?

Comment: If your employer is insisting you use mcafee then I suggest you approach your manager and explain this is stopping you work. Get mcafee removed from your dev machine or maybe work in a vm that doesn't have mcafee on it or obtain written confirmation that your management are aware company security policy is impacting your work.

Comment: Usually those exclusions are something managed by IT, so you should ask them to exclude folders on your PC.

Comment: Since McAfee allows you to exclude individual files I would assume it is not controlled by your organization. Try uninstalling McAfee to see if that resolves the issue and go from there.

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT yes I have full admin rights on my dev PC. the problem (AV false positive) goes away when I disable the AV real-time scanning.

Comment: @Andy I'm self-employed, so no problem with employer. I contacted McAfee who advised me to send them an email with details of the AV engine version, virus message and attach the file. I asked them how am I going to attach an .exe file in an email? lol. they should have a portal that facilitates uploading files and reporting false positives. i've got around the problem for now by disabling real-time scanning. now I'm looking at changing back to my old favorite Kaspersky.

Comment: It's not completely insane to put your entire dev environment on a vm. It is a bit slower, it is inconvenient but it's discrete. You can then store one or more working environment(s) as a backup file and run with minimal or no anti virus.